# Retrieving Facebook photos from a php script

Tags: php, facebook

I want to develop an app in php that I can link with a particular photo album in my Facebook profile (or with all my photos) in order to know the direct url link of each photo.

The idea is to make an php script who shows in chronological order my facebook photos like a presentation. Im php programmer, but I know nothing about Facebook integration API. So guys if you can suggest me ways to do this it will be nice. Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a class for retriving specific user profile pictures (PHP), you'll get the idea from it to create what you want:

```
<?php

class FBPicture {
    public $uid;
    public $dir;
    public $type = 'large';

    public function setUId ($id) {
        $this->uid = $id;
    }

    public function setDir ($dir) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
    }

    public function fetch ($_uid=null, $_dir=null, $_type=null) {
        if ($_uid === null)
            throw new CHttpException ('Facebook User ID or Username is not set.');
        if ($_dir === null)
            $_dir = '/storage/';
        if ($_type === null)
            $_type = 'large';

        $this->uid = $_uid;
        $this->dir = $_dir;
        $this->type = $_type;

        $dir = getcwd () . $this->dir;
        $type = $this->type;

        // request URI
        $host = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $_uid;
        $request = '/picture';
        $type = '?type=' . $type;

        $contents = file_get_contents ($host.$request.$type);

        // create the file (check existance);
        $file = 'fb_' . $uid . '_' . rand (0, 9999);
        $ext = '.jpg';

        if (file_exists ($dir)) {
            if (file_exists ($dir.$file.$ext)) {
                $file .= $dir.$file.'2'.$ext;

                if ($this->appendToFile ($file, $contents)) {
                    return str_replace ($dir, '', $file);
                }
            } else {
                $file = $dir.$file.$ext;
                touch ($file);

                if ($this->appendToFile ($file, $contents)) {
                    return str_replace ($dir, '', $file);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // false is returned if directory doesn't exist
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function appendToFile ($file, $contents) {
        $fp = fopen ($file, 'w');
        $retVal = fwrite ($fp, $contents);
        fclose ($fp);

        return $retVal;
    }
}

// sample usage:
// $pic will be the filename of the saved file...
$pic = FBPicture::fetch('zuck', 'uploads/', 'large'); // get a large photo of Mark Zuckerberg, and save it in the "uploads/" directory
// this will request the graph url: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?type=large

?>
```